# Which interface does a specific IP address will get routed over?

Tags: bash, netstat, iproute

Is there a way to determine which netdev or IP link interface that a given IP address will route over … in bash/shell language?

This is not about what an IP address is, given a network device name.

Given a destination IP address, bash would automagically determine (with OS assist from its internal IP route table, `netstat -i -n`) in printing the network device name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ip route get` is what you're looking for; maybe it's `ip route show to`, depending on whether you checking should be allowed to change the routing state.

See `man ip-route` for more details.

Comment: thanks a million.  it was `ip route get 9.9.9.9`.  I was crafting a nice configuration tool for setting up private root servers, hidden-master DNS, and four variants of split-horizon DNS for ISC Bind9 nameserver.   This answer will help me to determine if it is safe to install a private root servers or to install a certain variants of split-horizon.   Many thanks!

Comment: i also noticed that this `ip route` WILL NOT give a working route if one of its actual route’s physical link is down.  Kinda makes it a useless tool for any IP failover scenario.

Comment: ... but `ip route` literally sits at the source of your knowledge.  where do you think your failover route should be inferred if not by the very kernel that gets all the path status info??

Comment: so, by yanking an Ethernet cord from its RJ-45 socket, and the IP address is still in the route table, i have expected the `up route` NOT to give me its default gateway?

Comment: now you're deep inside how in IP, routers (in this case, your PC's routing table) decide on which path to take. Long story short: in absence of anything that tells your kernel that there's more than one route to some IP address, it simply won't be able to route traffic once one link becomes disfunctional, overloaded etc.